# Cloning html elements in javascript using for cicle

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, clone

I am trying to clone this li items, in order to save some writing and learn how to do it, of course. But I am not quite sure how to do it or is it even possible. Here is the code I have

```
(function (){

var docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var list = document.createElement("ul");
var listItem1 = document.createElement("li");
listItem1.textContent = "Item";
list.appendChild(listItem1);

for(var i=1; i<5; i++) {
    var listItem[i] = listItem.cloneNode(true);
    list.appendChild(listItem[i])
}

docFragment.appendChild(list);
document.body.appendChild(docFragment);

}())
```

Answer (score 1):

`var` is used to declare variables.
`var myArray[i]` makes no sense; you simply want to assign to the array element:

```
myArray[i] = someValue;
```

Comment: it's not what I have in mind. I just want to make it listItem2, listItem3 ... and so on. Wonder if this is possible... maybe listItem + [i] or I don't know...
Really sorry I'm new to javascript